# fill gridView with return dataset

Tags: c#, gridview, ado.net

how to pass ds from sql class to form class

in my form class

```
sqlCls floor = new sqlCls();
floor.getByFloor(floorNo);
reportFormDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; ******
```

in sql class . floor method

```
public DataSet getByFloor(int floorNo)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection conn = connectionCls.openConnection();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from table where floorsNo = " + floorNo, conn);

    SqlDataAdapter SE_ADAPTAR = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    SE_ADAPTAR.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridViews can take a DataSet as the DataSource just fine, no need to use a table.

Just do this:

```
sqlCls floor = new sqlCls();
var ds = floor.getByFloor(floorNo);
reportFormDataGridView.DataSource = ds;
```

You have a [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html) vulnerability in your code. Please consider using SQL parameters instead of unsanitized input.

So in your case it would be:

```
public DataSet getByFloor(int floorNo)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection conn = connectionCls.openConnection();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from table where floorsNo = @floorsNo", conn);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@floorsNo", floorNo);

    using(SqlDataAdapter SE_ADAPTAR = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
    {  
        SE_ADAPTAR.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

`SqlDataAdapter` implements the `IDisposable` interface so you can wrap it in a `using` block to automatically dispose of resources when execution flow leaves the scope.

Comment: it works thank you. about  SQL Injection i just read briefly about it. i am using win azure for my project do you advise me to use stored procedure to avoid SQL Injection ?

Comment: They key thing is to sanitize your input. Unless it was provided directly by your application, consider it dangerous. If you don't want to use SQL parameters, you should validate the input against a whitelist at the very least. I have edited the answer to include an example.